# react JavaScript ternary conditional operation

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

After I import the data as json from the detail page, in ProductDetail > brand > shoes > size.length
get the length
length is outputting in JSX.

But there is a problem.
There are also products without shoes data for each detailed product on the detail page.
I want to treat products without data as 0 instead of length as a ternary operator, but I don't know how to handle it.

```
<p>{ProductDetail && ProductDetail.brand.shoes.size.length}</p>
```

But here, data without brand is used using the ternary operator.
`<p>0</p> :`  I want to display it like this.

```
Nike Air Force ProductDetail > brand > shoes > size > length(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) <p>{length}</p>
jordan shoes ProductDetail > brand > shoes > size > length(0,1,2,3,4,5) <p>{length}</p>
adidas shoes ProductDetail > brand > x   -> Handles `<p>0</p>`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show `0` when an object is null or parent object is null, Try some like below

```
<p>{ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size?.length || 0}</p>
```

Basically with using optional chaining and `||` operator, The output will be

```
ProductDetail is null/undefined ==> 0
ProductDetail.brand null/undefined ==> 0
....
ProductDetail.brand.shoes.size has valid array ==> length
```

```js
let ProductDetail = { brand: { shoes: { size: [2, 3] } } };
console.log(ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size.length || 0);

ProductDetail = null;
console.log(ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size.length || 0);

ProductDetail = { brand: { shoes: null } }
console.log(ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size.length || 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator and optional chaining like this

```
<p>{ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size?.length ? ProductDetail.brand.shoes.size.length : null}</p>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined( reading '0') Products with null data do not have brand > x.

Comment: `ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size?.length ? ProductDetail.brand.shoes.size.length : null` and `ProductDetail?.brand?.shoes?.size?.length` are basically the same. No need to make it more complicated than it is.